# How to inject the changeset into the build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I work with a wrapper over ClearCase; so use None for the SCM. Triggering the build is implemented remotely via jenkins-cli. 
But how do inject the changeset into the build, so that:

a. It is visible under “Recent Changes” and
b. Identify the committers to notify in-case of a failure?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the [ClearCase Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin)? if you can you can then select ClearCase as the SCM.